# Show that $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} Du(x)[v]\,dv=0$

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry

Show that on a riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, if we integrate over the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\subset T_x M$, we have that $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \langle \mbox{ grad}u(x), v\rangle_x \,dv=0.$$

My approach: If we consider $dv$ as the measure of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, then   $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \langle \mbox{ grad}u(x), v\rangle_x \,dv=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} Du(x)[v]\,dv$$

Now, if we define $v'=-v$, then $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} Du(x)[v]\,dv=-\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} Du(x)[v']\,dv'$$

So, the integral is $0$. But I don't know if the change of variable is correct because we are on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and is this not the lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1):

The idea in the OP is correct.

Polar coordinates, and the induced product measure is definable even in the context of Lebesgue measure. (See for example Exercise 6, of Chapter 8 of Rudin Real & Complex Analysis.)

In fact, more generally if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix $n\times n$, then
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}f(Uw)\,dw =
\int_{S^{n-1}}f(w)\,dw
$$
This holds for $f\in L^1(S^{n-1})$ and in order to prove it we start with characteristic functions, using the facts

Fact A. $m_n(A)=m_n(UA)$, for $A\subset \mathbb R^n$, measurable, where $m_n$ is  the Lebesgue measure.

Fact B. If $D\subset S^{n-1}$ measurable, then
$$
\sigma_{n-1}(D)=n\, m_n\big(\{rw: w\in D,\,\,r\in [0,1]\}\big)
$$
where $\sigma_{n-1}$ the surface measure on $S^{n-1}$ and $m_n$ the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks! How you prove the last proposition?

Comment: @Steveee See my erdited qnswer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! sorry for this question but, how you use the fact of the invariant under orthogonal transformations? what are you trying to say with that in the problem.